# Как добавить Package в IDEA (не такого значка во вкладке File

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Извините за такой глупый вопрос, но я не могу добавить package, т.к. такого значка нет. Подскажите, где в настойках IDEA подключить данный функционал?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете добавить пакет в папку, только обычную папку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пакет можно добавить только в source root. Для того, чтобы сделать папку source root - клацните на папку правой кнопкой мыши - mark Directory as - Source root.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, папка изменит значек на синий, и уже можно будет добавлять туда пакеты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я нашла, спасибо!